# Build Java JDK for LibGDX packing

Tags: libgdx, java

I want to build my own java JDK so I can package my LibGDX game through [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [packr](http://github.com/libgdx/packr). [This](http://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Bundling-a-JRE) page suggests to use these [prebuilt jdks](http://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds), but that project has been discontinued. That page redirects to [another github](http://github.com/ojdkbuild/ojdkbuild) where I can get prebuilt jdks for Windows 64bit, however I need more builds for Mac and Linux (at least mac, because that's what I'm on).

I know there are other places to obtain built jdks for packing java applets and LibGDX games, but I rather just skip that hassle and build my own binaries with the jdk I'm using on my own computer.

If there are better ways to easily package my LibGDX game, I would love to know.

tl;dr: I want to build my own binary jdks so I can use [packr](http://github.com/libgdx/packr) or [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) to package my LibGDX game for distribution across multiple platforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building OpenJDK 8 yourself is not *that* hard. It's a bit tricky, but manageable once you figure out the important things.

First, you need to find the right version/tag of OpenJDK 8 to build. The current latest release appears to be `u112-b16`. You should clone the main 8-update repository and the subrepositories (corba jaxp jaxws langtools jdk hotspot nashorn):

```
hg clone https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u -u jdk8u112-b16 -r jdk8u112-b16
cd jdk8u
for repo in corba jaxp jaxws langtools jdk hotspot nashorn; do
  hg clone https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/$repo -u jdk8u112-b16 -r jdk8u112-b16
done
```

Then, take a look at the [README-builds.html](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/raw-file/b132c341cd87/README-builds.html) file that covers things like how to get all the dependencies you need for your platforms.

Once you have all the dependencies and everything you need to build, building itself looks like this:

```
cd jdk8u
mkdir build
cd build
bash ../configure \
          --with-milestone="fcs" \
          --with-update-version=112 \
          --with-build-number=b16 \
          # your other configure flags go here 
make all
```

Once the build completes, the JDK is available under `jdk8u/build/images/j2sdk-image/` and the JRE is available under `jdk8u/build/images/j2re-image`.

The AdoptOpenJDK folks have some fairly extensive docs that you might find useful: https://adoptopenjdk.gitbooks.io/adoptopenjdk-getting-started-kit/content/en/binaries/build_openjdk_8.html

If you run into issues, feel free to drop by `#openjdk` on `irc.oft.net`.

Comment: Thank you very much omajid! I'm wondering the licensing issues with building my own JDK without my own source as well.

Comment: IANAL, so I can't comment on any legal issues. If you are concerned about bootstrapping, you can bootstrap OpenJDK using gcj. See http://grokbase.com/p/openjdk/porters-dev/11220sn1wm/porting-openjdk-to-a-different-os-not-having-java